# Is there a major difference between codeigniter 1.7 and the latest version?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop, codeigniter

Basically, I began learning codeigniter today and bought a book on the subject. The book references version 1.7 and the version i am working with is 2.1.

There is an example controller in the book that looks like this:

```
<?php
class Start extends CI_Controller {

var    $base;
var    $css;


    function Start(){ 

        parent::CI_Controller();

        $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');
    $this->css = $this->config->item('css');      

        }            

function hello($name)

{

$data['css'] = $this->css;

$data['base'] = $this->base;

$data['mytitle'] = 'Welcome to this site';

$data['mytext'] = "Hello, $name, now we're getting dynamic!";
    $this->load->view('testview', $data);

   }  
}
```

However it will only work when i remove the following function:

```
function Start(){ 

        parent::CI_Controller();

        $this->base = $this->config->item('base_url');
    $this->css = $this->config->item('css');      

        }
```

Does anybody know why? If so, how do i call my css file from the config.

EDIT: The view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web Test Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base . "/" . $css; ?>">
</head>
<body>

<h1><?php echo $mytitle; ?></h1>
<p class='test'> <?php echo $mytext; ?> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There have been a lot of changes - you should see the [changelog](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html) if you wan't to know exactly what.

Without knowing exactly what your book tells you to do, I can only give you some pointers as to what to do to make your code work.

Firstly, when [creating a controller](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html) in CI 2.1, you should write it with PHP5 OOP style - not the PHP4 OOP style as you are doing in your example.

A simple example:

```
<?php
class Start extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
?>
```

Now this is your basic controller which just echoes 'Hello World!' when accessing `index.php/start`.
If you need to do something, get configuration variables or load some models/libraries before going to the index() method, you should create a [__construct()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) method which is called when the `Start` controller is instanciated. This `__construct()` method needs to call the construct from `CI_Controller` (the parent you are extending from). And you do that by typing `parent::__construct();` in your own construct method:

```
<?php
class Start extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
      //call models, variables, whatever here
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
?>
```

And that's basically what you need to know about making your controller work.

I don't know what 'call your css file from the config' means - I don't know what the css config item contains or what the book want's you to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for that. So what exactly is the difference between php 4 and 5 methods. The public and private functions?

Comment: Well, there is a lot of differences. PHP5 is more object orientated than PHP4; the implementation is much cleaner. I really think you should take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php.